# Parsing JSON Swift 3

Tags: json, facebook, swift3

I am running iOS 9.0, Swift 3 on Xcode8 and implementing Facebook into my app, the `result` object returns successfully as:

```
Optional({
    email = "usersEmail@yahoo.com";
    "first_name" = name;
    id = 1015396591;
    "last_name" = lastName;
    picture =     {
        data =         {
            "is_silhouette" = 0;
            url = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/s200x200/1915003_414206574090_5019436_n.jpg?oh=bf120460b36b26c648185d6777a&oe=5892EB78";
        };
    };
})
```

However, attempting to access the elements as: `result["email"] as! String`, notes the error `Type Any? has no Subscript Members`

How can I allow the element to be read?

Comment: Can you use this `result!["email"] as! String`

Comment: That did not work.  I had to do `let result = result as [String:AnyObject]`, then what you posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to get email

```
let result = result as! Dictionary<String,Any>
let email = result["email"] as! String
```

Comment: What i ended up doing was: `let result = result as! [String:AnyObject]`

Comment: The above answer is more SWIFTY.